# Is there a good ratio for Front End Hours to Datastore Reads?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

My app has two main costs the Front End Hours and the Datastore Read Ops.  The cost ratio is about 1:1, i.e. a typical day will have $100 in Front End hours and $100 in read operations.

Is there an ideal ratio between these services?  Obviously this is code dependent but I'm wondering if my ratio raises red flags on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking because of cost concern then I've found in 80%+ cases you could always benefit from more caching.

If the data being read from the datastore doesn't change that often then I would say that your costs are on the high end for datastore reads. I would advise you to improve your memcache usage, especially since the free tier usage of memcache on Google Cloud is extremely lenient.

If the data being read from the datastore changes a lot daily then I would expect the costs to be more or less equal, but even still you should be able to bring that down with a proper caching strategy.

Comment: In looking at it, I'm making like 21:1 reads to writes, so maybe if I cache as much as I can that'll bring it down.

Comment: That sounds like a good opportunity for some caching yes. :) 
I'd suggest calling memcache directly and not helper libs, it'll give you more control over the effectiveness.

Comment: If I memcache a query object, like myClass_set.  Will that still be a datastore hit as I iterate through it? Or does this list need to be fetched and then cached?

Comment: You will have to fetch the results, serialize and store the results in `memcache`.

Comment: Great I'll try it like this memcache.set('mykey', list(myClass.all().filter("test =", True).run())) to memcache the list of objects

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as ratio between Front End hours to Datastore Reads.

If your queries are heavy, lets all you do is search your DB, your Datastore Reads will be huge.

At the same time if you cache your data properly you can minimize your Datastore Reads.